# How to deploy a Laravel app to a sub-directory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-7

I'm new to Laravel framework so this question might be a little stupid but here's the problem:

I have a small project on my local machine and now I need to deploy my project to a live environment ( shared hosting ).

The problem is, my project needs to be stored in a sub-directory ( sub-folder ) of the main domain ( eg. my domain will be **main.com**, and the project will be at **main.com/my-project** ).
I've created a sub folder inside the public_html of the main domain, then I uploaded my project to that sub-directory. At first, when I went to the url **main.com/my-project**, I see a directory tree ( like localhost ), then I needed to click to public folder to go to my app. So I looked for the solutions on the internet and I tried the .htaccess way, here's my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But when I reload the url **main.com/my-project**, I kept receiving the message URL request not found.

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and still haven't figured it out. Any idea how I can solve this problem? Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04 Look at "Step Four — Create New Virtual Host Files"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping, well actually I figured it out somehow. Here's my solutions for anybody who might run into the same problem like I did:

Inside /public_html, I created a folder and named it my-project. Inside my-project folder, I placed all files & assets folders ( css, js ) and .htaccess file here.

Then I went back to the parent level ( same level as /public_html ), I created a folder and name it app-core. I placed all the other Laravel's folders & files here.

The structure is gonna be like this :

```
public_html

=app-core
--- All others files & folders except **public**
=my-project
--- index.php
--- css
--- js
--- .htaccess
```

Finally, I went back to edit the index.php like this :

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app-core/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../app-core/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And saved it, then everything was ready to go!

Comment: This is great to know. But I know that you have done. My 2 projects are live on this system too. But I suggest you that, this is also simple too.

Comment: Yeah your way is great too. If anybody can't get the job done by using my way, you guys should try following @A.ANoman way!

Comment: Tried this. Everything worked except file uploads. Uploaded files were saving to app-core/public/uploads folder. How do we fix this?

Comment: I did the same but now i'm recieving a "HTTP ERROR 500" in my site :(

Comment: @FernandoTorres What version are you using? Is it Laravel 8? I've tested this for newer version, this works for Laravel 7 :D

Comment: Thanks. But just to be clear, where did you place the Laravel 'public' folder?